# connecting Commodore 64 to a HDTV

Tags: retro-computing, commodore

I own a Commodore Vic 20 & Commodore 64 since way back in the day. They both work, but I would like to connect them to a HDTV. (1) Is this possible? (2) what cables do I need to connect to a HDTV?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Wrong place to ask. Google "C64 AV cable".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the wikipedia page:

> 8-pin DIN connector containing composite video output, separate Y/C
>   outputs and sound input/output

basicly youll need a tv with a component(composit) socket (red white yellow/green cables) or antenna

or any other cable where you can get an adaptor for S-Video or DIN Socket for
=)